# bind field at run time Crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to create a column on a crystal report. I am binding crystal report to .net class object collection at run time. Now one of the columns I need to bind to the object collection property which is another object to it’s property.
How do I do this ?

Comment: Please rephrase? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

domain of the qustion is not that cliear.

if the object what you need to display in the report is not in the detail section of the report you will be able to pass this as a parameter.

if this is not not working for you. create the report based on a xml schema. and genarate the report based on that schema.

1. http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_from_xml_file.htm
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/xmlcrreport.aspx